# Download, extract and copy file from a folder that has a version in its name

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script that downloads an compressed archive from an universal URL (in which new release of the software will automatically be presented), extracts it and copies a file called `wimboot` to a folder.

This is what I currently have:

```
sudo curl http://git.ipxe.org/releases/wimboot/wimboot-latest.tar.gz -o ./wimboot.tar.gz

sudo tar -zxvf ./wimboot.tar.gz #Extracts into a folder called "wimboot-2.5.2-signed", in it is the file I need ("wimboot").
cd ./wimboot*/
sudo cp wimboot /my-folder/
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a method that will allow me to do this?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What behavior do you see and what do you expect to be different?

Comment: using `cd` combined with a `*` wildcard might not work, since it is possible that there are multiple options (`wimboot-1`, `wimboot-2.4`, etc.)

Comment: I'm not able to access the outputted folder of an "latest-version"-archive using wildcards. I expect to access the outputted folder (in my current case "wimboot-2.5.2-signed") while not being bothered that the version, that is displayed in the name of the folder, could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built on top of the other answers and this worked for me:

```
#Create a temporary folder, this folder must be empty!
sudo mkdir temp

#Download the archive and save it in the temporary folder.
sudo curl http://git.ipxe.org/releases/wimboot/wimboot-latest.tar.gz -o ./temp/wimboot-latest.tar.gz

#Extract the downloaded archive to the temporary folder.
sudo tar xvf ./temp/wimboot-latest.tar.gz -C ./temp

#Search for and copy files with the name "wimboot" to the web directory.
sudo find ./temp/ -name 'wimboot' -exec cp {} /var/www/  \;

#Delete the temporary folder.
sudo rm -Rf temp
```

I do not recommend this for large archives.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `tar` for a file listing (`-t` option), which you can then grep for `wimboot` -- that should give you the relative path to the file also.  A naive first try would be something like:

```
src_file=$(tar tf wimboot.tar.gz | grep wimboot)
cp "$src_file" my_folder/
```

But you will probably want to add some error checking and stuff to that.  And probably a more complicated `grep` expression to ensure you get the one thing you're after.

There's also no need to extract the entire archive.  You can just ask `tar` to extract the file you're interested in:

```
tar zxf wimboot.tar.gz "$src_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've used a bit of your code and made it work with mine!